# parse string for key, value pairs with a known key delimiter

Tags: python, regex, string, dictionary

How can I convert a string to a dict, if key strings are known substrings with definite delimiters?  Example:

```
s = 'k1:text k2: more text k3:andk4: more yet'
key_list = ['k1','k2','k3']
(missing code)
# s_dict = {'k1':'text', 'k2':'more text', 'k3':'andk4: more yet'}
```

In this case, keys must be preceded by a space, newline, or be the first character of the string and must be followed (immediately) by a colon, else they are not parsed as keys. Thus in the example, `k1`,`k2`, and `k3` are read as keys, while `k4` is part of `k3`'s value.  I've also stripped trailing white space but consider this is optional.

Comment: Also keys can be preceded by beginning of string, unless that string is supposed to have a space at the beginning of it.

Comment: @chrisz ah yes!  I'll edit the text

Comment: @chrisz I don't know exactly what you mean... assume if the key string isn't directly preceded by a space (or other exceptions noted) and directly followed by a colon, it's part of the value (e.g., k4 in the question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` to do this:

```
>>> import re
>>> dict(re.findall(r'(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=^))(\S+?):(.*?)(?=\s[^\s:]+:|$)', s))
{'k1': 'text', 'k2': ' more text', 'k3': 'andk4: more yet'}
```

The regular expression requires a little trial-and-error. Stare at it long enough, and you'll understand what it's doing.

**Details**

```
(?:          
   (?<=\s)   # lookbehind for a space 
   |         # regex OR
   (?<=^)    # lookbehind for start-of-line
)     
(\S+?)       # non-greedy match for anything that isn't a space
:            # literal colon
(.*?)        # non-greedy match
(?=          # lookahead (this handles the third key's case)
   \s        # space  
   [^\s:]+   # anything that is not a space or colon
   :         # colon
   |
   $         # end-of-line
)
```

Comment: ah, thnks CS! :)

Comment: @ConfusinglyCuriousTheThird You're welcome ;-) Let me know if the regex fails on any input.